# How to get myself out of clan wars

Tags: clash-of-clans

I don't want to participate in clan wars...

Can't I make myself invisible from the list from which the leader or co leader chooses the war participants.???

Comment: ...leave the clan?

Comment: @Frank leave the clan, I think you will have a cool down of like 20 h or so before you can participate in wars again, but other than that, you don't NEED to participate in a war. You can't be "invisible from the list" but you can say you don't want to be in war. Other than that, they can still put you in, ask in clan chat if you cannot be in clan wars

Comment: Why all the downvotes? This is a perfectly legitimate question, and the game has a feature specifically for this purpose - to opt out of clan wars. Serious clans often request that their members opt out, leaving space for someone else, if they're not currently prepared - low on spells, hero down, or just busy that day. Leaving and re-joining your clan would be a really inconvenient way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

**There is an option to opt out for war.**

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'd add that this doesn't make you completely invisible on the list, but it does clearly mark you as not available. If the clan leader manually adds you to the war anyway, that's arguably their problem, not yours! :)